# How can I search TFS database for deleted folders/Items?

Tags: tfs

I need to locate items/folders that may have been deleted. Undeleting everything in the UI is not practical. Searching text files will not work because deleted items are not included in get latest.

Answer (score 2):

Click the *Show Deleted Items* (the double X icon) in the top of the Source Control Explorer and the view will include deleted files and folders.

[image: Show Deleted Items]